# Simplify sqrt-Inequality to prove monotonicity of a series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, roots

In order to prove, that the series $a_n = \sqrt[3]{n+1} - \sqrt{n}$ is monotone, I tried to prove $a_n > a_{n+1} ~\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$.
I want to know, if there is a neat, less chaotic approach than mine.
My approach goes as follows:
$$
a_n > a_{n+1}
\iff \sqrt[3]{n+1} - \sqrt{n} > \sqrt[3]{n+2} - \sqrt{n+1}
\iff \sqrt[3]{n+1} - \sqrt[3]{n+2} > \sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n+1}
$$
Now using that $a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ and $a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$, we obtain

$$
\iff \frac{(n+1) - (n+2)}{(n+1)^{\frac{2}{3}} + ((n+1)(n+2))^{\frac{1}{3}} + (n+2)^{\frac{2}{3}}} >
\frac{n - (n+1)}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1}}
$$
$$
\iff \frac{-1}{(n+1)^{\frac{2}{3}} + ((n+1)(n+2))^{\frac{1}{3}} + (n+2)^{\frac{2}{3}}} >
\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1}}
$$
$$
\iff \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1} < (n+1)^{\frac{2}{3}} + ((n+1)(n+2))^{\frac{1}{3}} + (n+2)^{\frac{2}{3}}
$$
The last equality hold true for all positive n because all root functions are monotone $(*)$ and so we have for all positive n that 
$$
(n+2)^{\frac{2}{3}} \overset{(*)}{\geq}
(n+1)^{\frac{2}{3}} \geq
\sqrt{n+1} \overset{(*)}{\geq} \sqrt{n}
$$

Comment: Perhaps showing that the derivative of $f(x)=(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/2}$ is always negative for positive values is easier?

Comment: $(n+1)^\frac 23 + (n+1)^\frac13(n+2)^\frac 13 + (n+2)^\frac 23 > 3(n+1)^\frac 23 > 2(n+1)^\frac 12 > n^\frac 12 + (n+1)^\frac 12$ 
And 
$\forall n \ge 0, \frac {(n+1)^\frac 23}{(n+1)^\frac 12} = (n+1)^\frac 16 > \frac 23$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\sqrt[3]{n+1} - \sqrt[3]{n+2} > \sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n+1}$

If some calculus is allowed, $\,\sqrt[3]{n+2} - \sqrt[3]{n+1}=\dfrac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{a^2}}\,$ for some $\,a \in (n+1,n+2)\,$  by the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), and $\,\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{b}}\,$ for some $\,b \in (n,n+1)\,$. It then follows that:

$$
\sqrt[3]{n+2} - \sqrt[3]{n+1} = \dfrac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{a^2}} \lt \underbrace{\dfrac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}} < \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{n+1}}}_{\text{because}\; n+1 \,\gt\, 1 \,\gt\, (2/3)^6 \;\text{}} \lt \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{b}} = \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}
$$

Comment: I understand the MVT bit but can you please share the reasoning behind the inequality with the bracket? I tried to show it and this is my work: $\frac{1}{3 \sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}} < \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}} \iff 2\sqrt{n+1} < 3 \sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2 \iff \frac{2}{3} < (n+1)^{-\frac{1}{6}} \iff (n+1) < \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^6$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik The inequality can be written as $\,\dfrac{2}{3} < \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}}{\sqrt{n+1}} = \sqrt[6]{\dfrac{(n+1)^4}{(n+1)^3}}= \sqrt[6]{n+1}\,$.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik P.S. `Where did I go wrong?` At the third step where you subtract the exponents $\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{2}=\color{red}{+}\frac{1}{6}$.